# Electron/NodeJS/VSCode: What kind of syntax or infrastructure problems won't show in Debug Console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

### Problem

When working with Electron and VSCode, I've had a few syntax problems in code but no errors/warnings showed up in either VSCode's debug console or the Electron Chromium consoles.

With the Electron Chromium console, I have made sure that I enabled all levels, and `Preserve log`.

### Examples

The problems that gave NO console clues include

- With certain page script, Not `main.js` or `rederer.js`, I didn't enable `nodeIntegration`, so no NodeJS modules worked
- Forgetting to add `let`/`var` when defining variables, coming from other scripting worlds.
- Forgetting to add `new` when creating objects.
- An ES6 class constructor signature changed, e.g., more input args introduced, but the object creation code didn't change accordingly.
- Hitting an undefined object.
- When dealing with HTML strings with JS, there are errors in the HTML strings.

I feel a dire need to figure out a full list of "silent" problems that won't ever have any IDE/interpreter feedback during dev in the JS/NodeJS/Electron land. Otherwise, I would lose too much time on stupid errors.

Or am I missing anything obvious? Tool configuration, or simply misunderstanding of the problems?

### Updates

I've discovered that `main.js` or `renderer.js` works with the debugger, but  since I'm using a thirdparty lib `electron-tabs`, not additional code linked to my `electron-tab`'s tab pages is supported by the debuggers. The above examples apply to those tab JS code. I don't know why yet, but at least this is a crucial detail.

Next, I'd love to know if adding more pages will make a difference.

Comment: Can I check your project? Maybe is it in github repo?

Comment: @tpikachu Thank you. Here it is: https://github.com/kakyoism/SOS This problem is driving me nuts. I've checked my `.vscode/launch.json`, but have no clue which properties to change.

Comment: Just accepted. Let me check. SOS lol? )

Comment: @tpikachu Thanks a bunch! You'll need `npm install electron --save` and `npm install electron-tabs --save`

Comment: Thanks but no newbie ;)

Comment: Ok. I think I need realtime communication with you.

Comment: @tpikachu I'm here, where to open the discussion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208318/discussion-between-tpikachu-and-kakyo).

Comment: Use a linter. I recommend https://standardjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found my problem after a lot of digging.

To my understanding, with Electron, we need to **include ALL scripts into the relevant processes**, e.g., main or renderer, to be able to use the debug consoles. Otherwise, no feedback will be available except for the basic linter that VSCode comes with.

After adding the offending scripts to my main HTML, so that it looks like:

```html
    <script>
        // You can also require other files to run in this process
        require('./renderer.js')
        require('./tab1.js')
    </script>
```

the debug console starts working on these additional scripts such as `tab1.js`.

But does it mean that I'd have to include all scripts to these two processes only?